# creating a windows service from existing web application

Tags: .net, windows-services

I have an web application in .net and it creates updates database after examining a .CSV fie .
Now, I want to create a windows service to do the same . how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to refactor and extract the logic (ie. examining the .csv file and updating the database) into a `Class Library`. You can then reference the library from your current web application. Next you would create a `new Windows Service project` and reference that same library. Note that you will need to copy some of your web.config settings (connection string) to an app.config in your windows service.

Depending on how much features you want your Windows Service to have, you can take a look at this opens source project to host/run your windows service: https://github.com/jgoz/muster